# Wordpress Search Using Multiple Dropdown Lists

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

How i can search multiple categories?

For a example I have 4 dropdown menus:

```
1. City
2. Area
3. Month
4. Products/Services
```

So when any user visits my site. a static page will open and there will be 4 dropdown lists to select and a button name search, after selecting from all 4 the categories, the search will get selected categories by user in my Wordpress.

[image]

Also check out http://gorillathemes.com/broker/?wptheme=Broker-Real-Estate-White-Style

Comment: No one can help in this please

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly your programming skills. Basically, you need to manually build the query on submit. There is not a native way of doing this in WordPress, as far as I know. That is why you will need to build it on your own, taking the selected parameters. The solution depends on the code you use for this, but usually within a form, the submit action will generate a query like

`?dropdown-name=selected-option-value&dropdown2-name=selected-option-value`

That could do the work. So doing a correct markup could be enough. keep in mind that the dropdown name is given by the name declared in  and the values are taken from the  attribute (the text shown to the user could be different than the value, for example, for user-friendliness purposes). That means that the select name should be the taxonomy name, and the value should be the term itself in order to make this work out of the box.

The format should be: `?city=mumbai&area=kurla&month=april&product=food` assuming that each of them represent `taxonomy-name=term`. I think that there is not a pretty-permalink format for these kind of queries.

Feel free to ask for clarification if needed. I hope this helps you.